# Need help fixing memory leak for elixir and sweet_xml library

Tags: memory-leaks, elixir, openstreetmap

I'm a newbie in elixir.

I've got the following `lib/osm.ex` file

```rb
defmodule Osm do
  import SweetXml

  def hello do
    :world
  end

  def main(args) do
    args |> parse_args |> process
  end

  defp parse_args(args) do
    {options, _, _} = OptionParser.parse(args, switches: [osm_file: :string, help: :boolean])
    options
  end

  def output_help() do
    IO.puts "Usage: osm [OPTION]"
    IO.puts ""
    IO.puts "  --osm-file  an osm-file to import"
    IO.puts "  --help      outputs this help-page"
  end

  def process([]) do
    IO.puts "No arguments given"
  end

  def process(options) do
    if options[:help] do
      output_help()
    else
      case options do
        [osm_file: _] ->
          process_osm_file(options[:osm_file])
      end
    end
  end

  def process_osm_file(file) do
    counts = %{:nodes => 0, :ways => 0, :relations => 0}
    cond do
      String.ends_with?(file, ".pbf") ->
        IO.puts "parse osm-pbf."
      String.ends_with?(file, ".osm.bz2") ->
        IO.puts "extract and parse osm-xml."
      String.ends_with?(file, ".osm") ->
        IO.puts "parse osm-xml."
        File.stream!(file)
         |> stream_tags([:node, :way, :relation], discard: [:node, :way, :relation])
          |> Stream.map(fn
            {_, node} ->
              process_element(node, counts)
          end)
          |> Enum.reduce(fn element, result ->
            result_modified = %{result |
              nodes: result[:nodes] + element[:nodes],
              ways: result[:ways] + element[:ways],
              relations: result[:relations] + element[:relations]
            }
            cond do
              rem(result_modified[:nodes], 1000) == 0 ->
                IO.write "\rnodes: " <> to_string(result_modified[:nodes]) <> "; ways: " <> to_string(result_modified[:ways]) <> "; relations: " <> to_string(result_modified[:relations]) <> "; mem: " <> to_string(:erlang.memory(:total))
              true -> true
            end
            result_modified
          end)
          |> Stream.run
          IO.puts ""
      true ->
        IO.puts "invalid osm-file extension."
    end
  end

  defp process_element(doc, counts) do
    case doc |> xmlElement(:name) do
      :node ->
        doc |> xmap(
          id: ~x"./@id"i,
          lat: ~x"./@lat"f,
          lon: ~x"./@lon"f,
          tags: [
            ~x"./tag"l,
            key: ~x"./@k"s,
            value: ~x"./@v"s
          ]
        ) |> process_node(counts)

      :way ->
        doc |> xmap(
          id: ~x"./@id"i,
          nd: [
            ~x"./nd"l,
            ref: ~x"./@ref"i
          ],
          tags: [
            ~x"./tag"l,
            key: ~x"./@k"s,
            value: ~x"./@v"s
          ]
        ) |> process_way(counts)

      :relation ->
        doc |> xmap(
          id: ~x"./@id"i,
          member: [
            ~x"./member"l,
            type: ~x"./@type"s,
            ref: ~x"./@ref"s,
            role: ~x"./@role"s
          ],
          tags: [
            ~x"./tag"l,
            key: ~x"./@k"s,
            value: ~x"./@v"s
          ]
        ) |> process_relation(counts)

      _ ->
        IO.puts "unhandled element"
    end
  end

  defp process_node(node, counts) do
    _ = node
    Map.put(counts, :nodes, counts[:nodes] + 1)
  end

  defp process_way(way, counts) do
    _ = way
    Map.put(counts, :ways, counts[:ways] + 1)
  end

  defp process_relation(relation, counts) do
    _ = relation
    Map.put(counts, :relations, counts[:relations] + 1)
  end
end
```

and the following `mix.exs` file

```
defmodule Osm.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :osm,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.7",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      escript: [main_module: Osm],
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  def application do
    [
      extra_applications: [:logger]
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:sweet_xml, github: 'kbrw/sweet_xml', app: false}
    ]
  end
end
```

I compile it with `mix escript.build`

I've downloaded the berlin-latest.osm.bz2 [file](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/berlin.html) and extracted the berlin-latest.osm file.

If I call `./osm --osm-file=berlin-latest.osm`

The script parses the xml-data and counts the nodes, ways and relations correctly, but the memory consumption is increasing until the end.

Is there a memory leak in the SweetXml library or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have installed your project and reproduced the issue: during the parsing, more and more memory is consumed whereas we are only counting occurrences -> I have reproduced the memory leak.

Comment: You subsequently produce billions of `%SweetXpath{}` structs _and_ map them to billions of your own maps. Why do you expect the memory to not grow up?

Comment: But nothing is stored, or kept after function have executed @mudasobwa, so do you imply that erlang vm does not free memory taken by data that have been created inside a function, after this function has executed ? or is it that the memory is occupied at a faster pace than it is freed ? your input as an experienced erlang developer would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: You are importing logger, are your logs growing?

Comment: No, the logs are not growing, I didn't use any logging yet. Even if I don't import logging, the memory is still growing.

Answer (score 5):

**I do not see something that would create a memory leak in your code.**

I did the following test: I removed progressively all the code using SweetXml, and it is when I withdrew the first part using SweetXml (i.e: `stream_tags([:node, :way, :relation], discard: [:node, :way, :relation])`) that the memory leak disappeared. **This clearly indicates that the memory consumption comes from SweetXml**

Reading the source code of [`SweetXml.stream_tags/3`](https://github.com/kbrw/sweet_xml/blob/710c1bafce7b7232709cb1d6c73c0058cf048feb/lib/sweet_xml.ex#L287) function, might bring you some answers. I haven't yet understood from where the leak comes from.

Edit: after a thorough inspection of the source code, I still haven't found the origin of the leak. I am starting to thing it is something even deeper, maybe linked to the way erlang VM works.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will open an Issue on the SweetXml github repository. I really don't have the experience of erlang/elixir to say, if the leak comes from the VM.

Comment: Several of the major contributors of SweetXml work in my company (including the CTO). Depending on the workload.. I might have an opportunity to discuss that subject with them. I will get back to you @RingoLeese in this case.

Comment: Have you discussed that subject @NathanRipert? Anyone else, who has an idea?

Comment: @Ringo Leese not really. I have rapidly discussed this subject with my CTO one week ago: you can have memory leaks in several case (in erlang in general), now, I need to compute if one of those case apply to this situation. I will get back to you as soon as I have, thank you for bringing back the subject.

Comment: *User advisory: Because of the way this module implements the search, it seems to me that it is a very inefficient way to implement our search. For example, when you search the tags, this algorithm first retrieves a list of all elements (xmlElement) in the document, then search the tag of each of those elements. For a large XML document containing many elements, this would likely be a very large list... It would be an interesting improvement if we could get `:xmerl_xpath.string/2` to return an Elixir `stream` instead of a `list`.* http://davekuhlman.org/elixir-xml-processing.html